# How to determine how often a statement in a nested loop is executed?

Tags: java, algorithm, complexity-theory, nested-loops

I am working through a section of a text on determining complexity of nested loops using recurrence relations. In this particular example I am trying to determine how many times the count variable will be incremented as a function of n.

This is the loop I am analyzing:

```
for (int i = 1; i <= n; i++) {
     int j = n;
     while (j > 0) {
           count++;
           j = j / 2;
     }
}
```

I think I understand that the first line would equate simply to n since it only executes for each value of n but it's the rest of it that I'm having trouble with. I think the answer would be something like n(n/2) except that this example is using integer division so I'm not sure how to represent that mathematically.

I've run through the loop by hand a few times on paper so I know that the count variable should equal 1, 4, 6, 12, 15, and 18 for n values of 1-6. I just can't seem to come up with the formula... Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The loop executes for `n` in the range `[1, n]`. It divides by 2 each time for the `j` variable, which is set to n, so the number of time the inner loop executes is `floor(l2(n)) + 1,` where l2 is the binary log function. Add up all such values from 1 to n (multiply by `n`).

Comment: +1 It would probably be a little bit clearer to express it as `floor(l2(i)) + 1` (j gets decremented each time through the inner loop; i controls the number of times the inner loop executes).

Comment: Actually, I take it back. It's not `floor(l2(i)) + 1` or `floor(l2(j)) + 1`. It's `floor(l2(n)) + 1`. The final answer is just `n` times that.

Comment: Thank you for the help! So if I understand correctly my entire loop would be described by n((floor(l2(n)) + 1)? And just to refresh my memory as this is my first time through many of these concepts, floor here means the largest integer not greater than l2(n)?

Comment: @Stavrosnco I just noticed that `j` is always defined as `n`. Therefore, Ted Hopp is correct. Sorry for any confusion.

Answer (score 0):

The inner `j` loop adds the location of the first set bit to count.

Each divide by 2 is the same as a right shift until all the bits are zero.

So, 2 would be 10 in binary, and have a value of 2 for the inner loop.
4 would be 100 in binary, and have a value of 3 for the inner loop.

The outer loop seems to just multiply the location of the first set bit by the number itself.

---

Here is an example with n = 13.

13 in binary is 1101, so the first set bit is at location 4.

4 * 13 = 52. 52 is the final answer.

Answer (score 0):

> for (int i = 1; i <= n; i++) {

This loop at the top goes through the **loop n times**.

> ```
>  int j = n;
>  while (j > 0) {
>        count++;
>        j = j / 2;
>  }
> ```

This loop here goes through the **loop log(n) times**, noting that it is a base 2 log since you are dividing by 2 each time.

Hence, the total number of counts is **n * ceiling(log(n))**